# Разница во времени в php и javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такие значения полей:

```
date1 = 10/18/2011
time1 = 0:00
date2 = 31/18/2011
time2 = 0:00
```

На JavaScript считаем разницу дней вот так:

```
var date1 = $('input[name=date1]').val()+' '+$('select[name=time1]').val();
var date2 = $('input[name=date2]').val()+' '+$('select[name=time2]').val();
var rent_time_1 = new Date(date1);
var rent_time_2 = new Date(date2);
var nDaysLeft = rent_time_2 > rent_time_1 ? Math.ceil((rent_time_2 - rent_time_1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) : null;
```

На php считаем так:

```
$rent_time_1 = $IN->GBL('date1', 'POST').' '.$IN->GBL('time1', 'POST');
$rent_time_1 = strtotime($rent_time_1);
$rent_time_2 = $IN->GBL('date2', 'POST').' '.$IN->GBL('time2', 'POST');
$rent_time_2 = strtotime($rent_time_2);
$days = ($rent_time_2 - $rent_time_1) / 86400;
```

На JS получается 14 дней, а на php 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так в JS у вас ceil, а в PHP нет? Вот вам и разница: Math.ceil округляет вперёд и получается 14, а PHP видимо путём отрезания (в меньшую) и получается 13.

Answer (score 0):

А где правильно считает, в php или javascript?

Comment: в javascript

Comment: А какие даты ты сравниваешь?

Comment: подправил, 18 и 31

Comment: $days = ceil($rent_time_2 - $rent_time_1) / 86400);
в php замени соответствующую строку на эту.